# C# remove item from list of integers int[] l = {1,2,3} - or use recursion to add them

Tags: c#, list, recursion, integer, sum

So there's [this](https://blog.svpino.com/2015/05/07/five-programming-problems-every-software-engineer-should-be-able-to-solve-in-less-than-1-hour) blog  that gives Five programming problems every Software Engineer should be able to solve in less than 1 hour and I'm just revisiting some of the concepts.

The first question reads

*Write three functions that compute the sum of the numbers in a given list using a for-loop, a while-loop, and recursion.*

Obviously the for- and while-loops are easy, but i started out with

```
int[] l = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
```

Is it at all possible to pop an item off the list and then pass the shortened list every time?

An attempt I saw in python:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
def recurse_count(lst):
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return lst[0]
    else:
        i = len(lst) - 1
        subtotal = lst[i] + lst[i - 1]
        lst.pop() #into the void with you
        lst[-1] = subtotal
        return recurse_count(lst)
```

Would it be possible with a int[] in c# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very elegant solution would be:

```
static public int sumThisUp(IEnumerable<int> list)
{
    return list.FirstOrDefault() + (list.Any() ? sumThisUp(list.Skip(1)) : 0);
}
```

Comment: Indeed, elegant and efficient, but I'd rather call `.Any()` not on `list`, but on `list.Skipt(1)` (maybe introduce a local variable?)

Comment: @AlexSikilinda It is more elegant without a local variable. I wasn't pointing for an efficient or fast solution, but a one-liner. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I do belive the List-class has a simple removeAt(int)-method. A recursive method would look like this:

```
public int sumThisUp(List<int> list) {
    int result = list[0];
    list.removeAt(0);
    return (list.length > 0) ? result + sumThisUp(list) : result;
}
```

Alternatively if you dont wanna edit the orginal list this would do:

```
public int sumThisUp2(List<int> list, int index = 0) {
   int result = list[index++];
   return (list.Count > index) ? result + sumThisUp2(list, index) : result;
}
```

Comment: Modifying the list in such function is definitely a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible in C#.
But I want to introduce some trick first: instead of modifying the source list we can just pass the start index. It will be much faster:

```
private static int Sum(int[] array, int startIndex)
{
    if (startIndex >= array.Length)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return array[startIndex] + Sum(array, startIndex + 1);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    int result = Sum(array, 0);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
public int Sum(int[] numbers, int startAt = 0)
{
    if (startAt == numbers.Length)
        return 0;
    return numbers[startAt] + Sum(numbers, startAt + 1);
}
```